# JAva query from SQL-Server view

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, view

I have a Java aplication that retrieves data from SQL server.

The queries are of the form

```
SELECT field1, field2...
FROM [PRODUCTION].[INNOVATOR].[someTable]
WHERE NOT date = ''
```

This works fine.

However, I created for a user dedicated view, that has quite complex structure, including multiple JOINs.

I want to retrieve data from this view while avoiding the debug of this SQL in the Java environment.

So, I placed the name of the view instead of ***someTable***.
Sound simple, but I get constantly an error message saying that the is not found.

Any idea why?

Comment: Chances are the problem is in the view and we would need to see that view.

Comment: *‘…an error message saying that **the is** not found’* – there's a word missing between the two words I've highlighted in bold. Is it a view that was missing or, perhaps, a column? If it was a view, what was the exact name that you put after `CREATE VIEW`? Are you certain that the view was created in the schema `INNOVATOR` of the database `PRODUCTION`? And if the missing object was a column, then check the view definition's main SELECT clause to see if the view actually returns a column by that name.

Answer (score 0):

Check who the owner of the newly created view is. Since the fully qualified name of a view is `Database.Owner.View`, the query above will only work if the view owner is "`INNOVATOR`". Replace "`INNOVATOR`" with the view owner.